# Configure local Tomcat server on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure a local Tomcat server in IntelliJ. [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-and-managing-application-server-integration.html) link suggests I should see an `Application Servers` option in `Build, Execution, Deployment` but it's not there. I'm using `Community 2021.1`. How do I configure this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in Community edition:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html